# Maximize Variable domain Mixed Integer Optimization

Tags: programming, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to do a mixed integer optimization using Mathematica 11.0. I have a set of variables $\in Integers$ and a set of variables in $\in Reals$ I try to solve it by

```
Maximize[{objective, constraints}, variables, regions];
```

where region is $\{(x_{101}|x_{102}|....)\in Integers,(a_{101}|a_{102}|....)\in Reals,(b_{101}|b_{102}|....)\in Reals\}$

Maximize reporting error

> Maximize: variable domain

How should I solve an optimization problem that have multiple region specifications ?

Comment: Please give a simple example that shows the problem.

Comment: The problem is really big, I will have to create some other small problem that have mixed regions to test the behavior. But does mathematica support some variables in Integers space and some in Reals space ? if a subset of constraints are non-linear but objective function is linear ?